# JSON ajax and jquery, cannot get to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following script in my javascript...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/ajax',
    data: {email: val},
    success: function(response) {   
             alert(response);
    }
});
```

And my php file looks like this...

```
    if ($_REQUEST['email']) {

$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_REQUEST['email']));
if (!$q -> rowCount()) {

    echo json_encode(error = false);
}
else {

    echo json_encode(error = true);
}

    }
```

I cannot get either the variable error of true or false out of the ajax call?

Does it matter how I put the **data** into the ajax call?

At the minute it is as above, where **email** is the name of the request, and **val** is a javascript variable of user input in a form.

Comment: Are you using firebug or a similar tool to view the AJAX request/response?

Comment: I have firebug lite for chrome. The ajax request was sucessfull but was returning [object]:[object] before.

Comment: Good deal. Thanks for the update. FYI the chrome developer tools are pretty darn good themselves if you want to try to ween yourself off of firebug lite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead. Your current code should give you a syntax error.

```
if (!$q -> rowCount()) {

    echo json_encode(array('error' => false));
}
else {

    echo json_encode(array( 'error' => true ))
}
```

Comment: This works but why does it have to be in an array? Thanks Interstellar

Comment: Because `json_encode()` takes a mixed argument as its parameter, but more than that an array is the most logical structure to store a key, value pair in. The array eventually gets translated into `{"error":true}`

Comment: This works but how do I call the variable now? error isn't it, and I tried response['error'], response[error], response["error"]? This JSON stuff is annoying lol.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the return parameter is json

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/ajax',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {email: val},
    success: function(response) {   
             alert(response);
    }
});
```

PHP FILES

```
if ($_REQUEST['email']) {

   $q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
   $q -> execute(array($_REQUEST['email']));
   if (!$q -> rowCount()) {
       echo json_encode(error = false);
       return json_encode(error = false);
   } else {

       echo json_encode(error = true);
       return json_encode(error = true);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I thought the problem was without dataType.